# Render parts in SSRS report asynchronously

Tags: sql-server, asynchronous, stored-procedures, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm trying to create an SSRS report and I'm using a lot of SQL queries there.

I have several tabs that shows different data to the user.

Can I render the stored procedure in all the tabs asynchronously but to show the user only the data he's suppose to see in the current tab?

The data in the other tabs should be loaded in the background.

Is it possible?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

All queries run when the report is run. SSRS renders only the page the user is currently viewing, so there is a mild saving there, but the data behind it is still generated and available.